# RequireJS not loading module before use its variables

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm getting an undefined error from a new library I just plugged in to `requireJS`. I know the undefined error is related with the `'wNumb'` module not loading before is used. If I load `'wNumb'` module in `config.js` like this: `require(['main', 'wNumb']);` everything works.

```
// conifg.js
require.config({
  paths: {
    'main': 'main',
    'socketio': './libs/socket.io/socket.io',
    'plotly': './libs/plotly/plotly-latest.min',
    'renderDataToPlotly': './scripts/renderDataToPlotly',
    'noUISlider': './libs/noUiSlider.8.5.1/nouislider.min',
    'wNumb': './libs/wnumb-1.0.2/wNumb',
    'sliders': './scripts/sliders',
    'makePlotlyWindowResponsive': './scripts/makePlotlyWindowResponsive'
  }
});

require(['main']);
```

---

```
// main.js
define([
  'socketio',
  'sliders', //---------------------------------------------> NOTE: sliders.js loading here
  'makePlotlyWindowResponsive',
  'renderDataToPlotly'
  ],
  function(io, sliders, makePlotlyWindowResponsive, renderDataToPlotly) {
    //
  }
);
```

---

```
// sliders.js
define(['noUISlider', 'wNumb'], function(noUISlider, wNumb) {
  console.log(wNumb); // ---------------------------------------------------> undefined
});
```

**Question**: Why is this happening? Should not `'wNumb'`have been loaded by the time `console.log(wNumb);` executes?

Thank you

Comment: are you sure the wNumb module define something ? Maybe it has been loaded but it exports nothing

Comment: Pretty sure. If `'wNumb'` exported nothing, placing it in `config.js` inside the `require(['main', 'wNumb']);` would not make a difference, but it does in deed.

Comment: do you have something in the `noUISlider` variable ?

Comment: I found out what was wrong @oliv37. I will post the answer. Thanks for your time

Comment: I think you should use [shim](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim)  as one of the requirejs benefits is to not use the window global variable

Comment: I'm trying to rewrite wNumb to exports as an anonymous module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, when you have trouble with a library you are using with RequireJS, you should check how it exports itself. The documentation will sometimes tell you what it is compatible with. Otherwise, you have to read the source code. To use wNumb 1.0.2 with RequireJS have have it behave mostly like a proper AMD module you must use a shim:

```
shim: {
    wNumb: {
        exports: "wNumb",
    },
}
```

This will give to the module the value of the global variable `wNumb` (which is the same as `window.wNumb`). This is how you get libraries that don't know anything about AMD but export themselves in the global space to work with RequireJS.

However, **if you can upgrade wNumb to 1.0.4 that would be better** because this version has introduced the [proper code](https://github.com/leongersen/wnumb/blob/8d55075e77bda7c91acbc552fc1cb28346ca6ce4/wNumb.js#L3) to make `wNumb` a proper AMD module: it calls `define` when it detects that there is an AMD loader available. You don't need a `shim` then.

Comment: I went for changing the `wNumb`code myself introducing the [code](https://github.com/leongersen/wnumb/blob/8d55075e77bda7c91acbc552fc1cb28346ca6ce4/wNumb.js#L3) you pointed out. It's good to know what `exports` inside `shim`actually does. Thanks @Louis

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was going on inside the `'wNumb'` module. I read `'wNumb'` code and saw at the end of the file this:
[image]

Apparently, `'wNumb'` was being exported to the *window* object. When I use `window.wNumb` (1, on the image) inside `sliders.js`, it returns the expected function (2, on the image). As a proof:
[image]